# Pandas: Pivoting multiple tables into single and counting occurences

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table that joins multiple (more than 8) data frames into one.

The tables have multiple columns, but I'll keep it simple here:

```
Table1

week        project 
42          ABC
42          FGA
42          ZTR
44          HTZ
44          UZR
44          LOP
46          POL
46          ZTT
46          ART
46          ART
...
```

In some weeks there may be not any occurrence of any project. Table 2, 3, 4 and so on will certainly have a different number of weekly occurrences.

**The only common column accross all tables it the week column. Some tables have more some less columns, also column headers may vary. The week column is the only common column across all and, as I assume, is sufficient here to be used solely.**

My goal is to count the number of occurrences across all tables per week. Ultimately, what I'd like to achieve is:

```
index  table1  table2  table3  table4  table5
42       3       3       4       11      23
43       0       4       10      15      7
44       3       12      8       9       1
45       0       7       0       0       8
46       4       6       7       0       22
47       8       3       12      6       0
```

Such counting would be quite easy in excel, simply by using a pivottable with counting.
How would I proceed in such scenario in Python?

Comment: Use concat to create one dataframe that includes everything and use pivot_table to get the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concat` with the `keys` argument and a follow up `groupby` with `unstack`.

The thing to note here is that your inferring the key manually, it would be better if each table had an id to show what source it came from.

```
tables = [df1,df2] # if you want to make the keys dynamic, 
#tables = table_dict = dict(zip([f'table {i}' for i in range(1,len(tables) + 1)],tables))

df_new = (
    pd.concat(tables, axis=0, keys=["table1", "table2"])
    .set_index("week", append=True)
    .groupby(level=[0, 2])
    .count()
    .unstack(0)
)

     project       
      table1 table2
week               
42         3      3
44         3      3
46         4      4
```

Comment: thanks. however, something quite strange happens. I receive a two level column header. First level appears to be all columns from table 1 (week, project, owner, date), second level appears to be a repetition of my desired pivot table (the numbers are correct, but replicated for each column of table1 over and over again).

Comment: hi @Botan please provide a sample that mimics your input/output and i'll gladly help. It's hard to write a solution with only guess work.